# Concatenar string com Vue no href

Tags: html, vue.js

Preciso jogar essa URL dentro do href:

```
http://localhost:62828/colecoes/channel.aspx?channelId=30271973&category=4
```

Porém, no lugar de **channelId=30271973** eu preciso concatenar com *{{colecao.Id}}*

Abaixo o meu href:

```
<h3 class="item-title"><a href="">{{colecao.tituloCanal}}</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<h3 class="item-title"><a :href="'http://localhost:62828/colecoes/channel.aspx?channelId=' + colecao.Id + '&category=4'">{{colecao.tituloCanal}}</a></h3>
```

Ou

```
<h3 class="item-title"><a v-bind:href="'http://localhost:62828/colecoes/channel.aspx?channelId=' + colecao.Id + '&category=4'">{{colecao.tituloCanal}}</a></h3>
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: **:)** ... [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

Podes usar um valor reactivo (`computed`) para isso, se fizeres a concatenação no template ele não vi conseguir fazer cache e vai calcular a cada `render`.

Seria assim:

Template:

```
<h3 class="item-title"><a :href="url">{{colecao.tituloCanal}}</a></h3>
```

Componente:

```
computed: {
    url(){
        return `http://localhost:62828/colecoes/channel.aspx?channelId=${this.colecao.Id}&category=4`;
    }
}
```